# How to send a request as a specific user agent

Tags: javascript, angular, express, googlebot, prerender

I implemented pre-rendering on the server side for my Angular app (I will pre-render only if some search bot is sending a request), and I want to see if everything is pre-rendered as it should. When I navigate to my website I will got the usual SPA app since the sender of the request is not any search bot, but my browser. How can I simulate that the request is sent from some search bot (Google Bot for example)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to differentiate between humans request and a bots request, to stop bots from spamming people use CAPTCHA. can you show what have you tried as of now to distinguish between bots and human

Comment: I am not talking about bots as a automated program that will try to call my endpoints. I am talking about the search engine bots that will try to crawl my website and index it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few ways to do it:

- From [prerender.io](https://docs.prerender.io/article/15-getting-started) docs:

> To see a prerendered page exactly how the crawlers will see it, you
> can set your User Agent in your browser to Googlebot and visit your
> URL, or run this on a command line and change [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to your
> URL:

```
curl -A Googlebot https://www.example.com/
```

- Another way is to override the user agent string in Chrome Dev Tools. Here is the article that shows how to do it: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/override-user-agent/
- You can use [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) Chrome extension

Comment: So is this working and solved your problem?

Comment: Yup... I used first solution, but also I tried the second one, and it also works... I didn't try the third solution but I guess it will also do the job...